# Database not showing with pgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I created a database using pqsl in the command line of my Mac with tables and users. Yet, when I connect to my psql database using pgAdmin4 it doesn't show my database?

1. Registered a server with name `localhost`.
2. Set the username to match the name of a user in the database I create using the command line.
3. Host name set to `localhost`.
4. Maintenance Database was set to the name of my database.
5. Set role to the same name as the user.
6. Tap Save.

Then under databases I don't find the name of my database at all, just `api` with none of my created tables??

Thanks for any help!

Comment: 1) What is the name of the database you created?  2 ) What `port` is the server you created the database running on? 3) There is no reason to set the `role` name.  4) There is no `psql` database, there is a Postgres(ql) database. 5) The Maintenance Database should be left as `postgres`.

Comment: The database name is `localdb`. Port number is `5432`. I was just using the shorthand `psql` because of the command. I fully realize the name isn't psql.

Comment: Assuming you are connecting to same Postgres cluster in `pgAdmin` as in `psql` then in `pgAdmin` in the Browser it should be *Servers* --> *localhost* --> *Databases* --> *localdb*.